# Postgres Perform Multi table data comparison

Tags: database, postgresql-9.4

I have the following table structures in a Postgres DB:

Table zones:

```
id - int, PK
name - varchar
```

Table zone_boundaries

```
id - int, PK
zone_id - FK (zones.id),
boundary - polygon
```

Table vehicles

```
id - int, PK
vehicle_registration - varchar
```

Table vehicle_logs

```
id - int, PK
vehicle_id - int, FK (vehicles.id)
latitude - float
longitude - float
```

The boundary column in the zone boundaries table holds the latitude/longitude coordinates of the zone specified by the zone_id as polygon data.

Now, I want to get the number of all vehicles whose lat/lng coordinates fall within the boundary of a zone in the zone_boundaries table in a select statement. How do I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

Getting this one pass will be tricky.  First you'll need to convert you latitude and longitude , for example:

```
ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(x y)');
```

After that you can use ST_Intersects. St_Intersects will returns whether or not two geometries intersect.  Alternatively you can use ST_CONTAINS.